# Flurry context in a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, this, android-context, flurry

I need to use Flurry within a **Fragment** in my Android app.

I insert the following code in `onStart()`:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    //Log.i("About get activity","About get activity "+getActivity().hashCode());
    FlurryAgent.onStartSession(getActivity(), "WXXXXXXXX");
}
```

and in on stop:

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    FlurryAgent.onEndSession(getActivity());
    super.onStop();
}
```

Is this code correct? Do I pass the context as `getActivity()`, `this` or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's correct, you could also use:

```
getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

which is the context for the entire application and not specific to that particular `Activity`.

As a side note, if it happens to you to get some weird crashes, specially when you press quickly the back button removing all the fragment in your back stack, it may be that `getActivity()` is returning null.

Comment: If my app has one activity and four fragments then Will flurry report four different sessions for each fragment or it will be just one session?Can you please elaborate.

Comment: Official Flurry documentation for onStartSession and onEndSession explain it very clearly: http://support.flurry.com/index.php?title=Analytics/Code/Doc/Android

Comment: Hi @fasteque I use google analytics and I can't see apps' fragments in google analytics, Only I can see FragmentActivity. If I use Flurry, can I see fragments in Flurry ?

Comment: @MustafaOlkun fragments are part of the Android framework, not Flurry or Google Analytics. What's your problem? I suggest you to ask a new question will all the information about the issue you are facing. Thanks.

Comment: @fasteque I've asked before there ==> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25473383/how-to-track-fragments-in-my-application-with-google-analytics 
Thank you.