# How to track Fragments in my application with Google Analytics

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-analytics

I use Google Analytics v3 for my Application and I use fragments in app.

Google analytics only shows FragmentActivity screen so I don't see that users' use fragments.

Google analytics only this.

[image]

I wrote each fragment below code

```
@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        tracker = EasyTracker.getInstance( getActivity() );
        EasyTracker.getInstance( getActivity() ).activityStart( getActivity() );  // Add this method.
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        EasyTracker.getInstance( getActivity() ).activityStop( getActivity() );  // Add this method.
    }
```

How do I do for see all that use fragments.

Thank you.